# Why is jQuery.getJSON structured the way it is?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Why is the getJSON function structured this way?

```
 $.getJSON( url [, data ] [, success ] )
```

Instead of just returning an object, i.e.:

```
 var myjson = $.getJSON( url [, data ])
```

Comment: One word: Asynchronous. The variable cannot be assigned a value, as the response will be coming later. While waiting for that, any code below that line will keep executing. When the data is received, your callback (success handler) will execute.

Comment: your `myjson` is actually a promise object. For a detailed answer see [how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Wow- Now I understand the principle/need behind a promise object too! Thanks. - Also Thanks Blex I get it. If not done that way I might use the variable before it is ready. Thank you.

Comment: I am sorry this question got down-voted. Several of us where wondering and researching it. It was a case of not seeing the forest for the trees...Asynchronous!! DUH!! ----- ALSO: HOW DO I MARK THIS SOLVED BTW?

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted, it's an extremely good beginner question.

Answer (score -1):

Because it returns a [jqXHR](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) object that contains responseText and responseXML properties, as well as a getResponseHeader() method. When the transport mechanism is something other than XMLHttpRequest (for example, a script tag for a JSONP request) the jqXHR object simulates native XHR functionality where possible. Basically, how would you know if the request was successful?